# How to initialize an array of structures within a function?

Tags: c

In the make_quad() function below, how do I set the default values for the vertex_color array in the quad_t structure?

```
/* RGBA color */
typedef struct {
    uint8_t r,g,b,a;
} rgba_t;

/* Quad polygon - other members removed */
typedef struct {
    rgba_t vertex_color[ 4 ];
} quad_t;
```

Elsewhere, a function to make and init a quad:

```
quad_t *make_quad() {
    quad_t *quad = malloc( sizeof( quad_t ) );
    quad->vertex_color = ??? /* What goes here? */
    return ( quad );
}
```

Obviously I can do it like this:

```
quad->vertex_color[ 0 ] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
...
quad->vertex_color[ 3 ] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
```

but this:

```
quad->vertex_color = {
    { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF },
    { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF },
    { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF },
    { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF }
};
```

...results in "*error: expected expression before '{' token*".

EDIT: Fixed a couple typos

Comment: Missign semicolon after rgba_t vertex_color[ 4 ] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a number of errors in your code, I've corrected them all here.  `quad_t` was already defined in `<sys/types.h>` so I changed it to `myquad_t`.

Basically, you can't statically init memory that's dynamically allocated at run-time, so what you can do is create a global which is initialized at compile time which you then use `memcpy` to copy into your dynamically allocated memory.

Here is an explanation of [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <stdint.h>

/* RGBA color */
typedef struct rgba {
    uint8_t r,g,b,a;
} rgba_t;

/* Quad polygon - other members removed */
typedef struct quad {
    rgba_t vertex_color[ 4 ];
} myquad_t;

static const myquad_t init_quad = {
     .vertex_color[ 0 ... 3 ] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF } 
    };    

myquad_t *make_quad() {
    myquad_t *q = malloc( sizeof( myquad_t ) );
    memcpy(q , &init_quad, sizeof( myquad_t ) );
    return ( q );
}    

int main(void) {

    myquad_t * q = make_quad();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post the actual code. This, for example:

```
typedef {
    uint8_t r,g,b,a;
} rgba_t;
```

won't compile. And it seems you are trying to do assignment, not initialisation. If you had declared the struct properly, you would be able to say:

```
rgba_t t = { 1,2,3,4 };
```

but not:

```
t = { 1,2,3,4 };
```

Comment: I left out the 'struct' keyword when I typed it out. I've fixed it above... and unless I've missed something else, that does compile.

Comment: @Artelius not of brace enclose initialisation values.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
memset(quad, 0xFF, sizeof(quad_t));
```

Answer (score 1):

In C99 you could do something like

```
*quad = (quad_t const){
  .vertex_color = {
    { .r = 0xFF, .g = 0xFF, .b = 0xFF, a. = 0xFF },
    { .r = 0xFF, .g = 0xFF, .b = 0xFF, a. = 0xFF },
    { .r = 0xFF, .g = 0xFF, .b = 0xFF, a. = 0xFF },
    { .r = 0xFF, .g = 0xFF, .b = 0xFF, a. = 0xFF },
  }
};
```

where the right hand side is a so-called compound literal.
Any modern compiler should implement this in the most efficient way.

But it would probably be better to be a bit more systematic

```
#define RGBA_INITIALIZER { .r = 0xFF, .g = 0xFF, .b = 0xFF, a. = 0xFF }
#define QUAD_INITIALIZER {                      \
.vertex_color = {                               \
  RGBA_INITIALIZER, RGBA_INITIALIZER,           \
  RGBA_INITIALIZER, RGBA_INITIALIZER            \
  }                                             \
}
```

and then just write

```
*quad = (quad_t const)RGBA_INITIALIZER;
```